# Как указать бота в discord-py?

Tags: discord.py

Я сделал команду user. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы когда кто-то писал **!user @Мой_Бот**, то он выдавал какое-либо сообщение. Как это сделать?

Comment: Какую библиотеку используешь? И код, если можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из контекста (`ctx`) команды получаем объект сообщения - `ctx.message`. Затем получаем список всех упоминаний из сообщения - `ctx.message.mentions`.

Проверяем, чтобы атрибут `user` объекта бота (`bot.user`) находился в этом списке и выводим соответствующее сообщение:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=discord.Intents.all())

@bot.command()
async def user(ctx):
    if bot.user in ctx.message.mentions:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, вы упомянули меня!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'В этом сообщении меня никто не упомянул')

bot.run('TOKEN')
```